# Form security for html/css input

Tags: php, forms, security

I'm building a template tool in PHP where I want to allow users to input html/css content into form textareas. Currently I am running:

Strip_Tags(allowing only basic html and style tags)
then:
 
htmlentities
 
then:
 
htmlspecialchars_decode(converting allowed tags back from `&lt;br&gt;` for example)

My form action uses the `htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` method.

Any suggestions on what else is needed to secure this tool for online consumption? Do I need to validate, and if so what filter? Are there certain pieces of malicious code I should also strip out?

Based on the required input (html/css only), is there a best practice? I (currently) don't use databases, but would love an umbrella solution if I need to scale up.

Thanks

Comment: Malicious in what sense? As in potentially harmful to a database or your server? Or for when you retrieve and use the input?

Comment: @Tom Malicious as in I don't want any nasty surprises, being that security is over my head! I assume I am doing enough to remove any nasty code retrieved by the functions I am running, however I am not aware of all the vulnerabilities out there. If I've effectively secured the output string, what other things could someone do to attack the server or a database (if I add one later)

Comment: The first line of protection should be escaping your strings, **mysqli** for instance has the method `real_escape_string()` which prevents any code that could be interpreted as SQL from being executed, this method is used mainly for database security. Other than that you should be good to go from a basic security standpoint.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for that. I don't need to escape any of what `real_escape_string()` does without a database? There's no way someone could create one and if so do anything with it? So basically I'm good with what I got, and add the `real_escape_string()` later when I use a database? Is that correct?

Comment: Essentially, you just need to make sure a user couldn't insert PHP code and have it executed on your server, e.g. `';php_info();die();` could show someone sensitive info, but so long as quotation marks and such are escaped you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks @TomWalters. Throw it up as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of protection should be escaping your strings, `mysqli` for instance has the method `real_escape_string()` which prevents any code that could be interpreted as SQL from being executed, this method is used mainly for database security.

You should ensure users can't execute malicious code on your server by escaping slashes, on way of doing this is by using the [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function.

Other than that you should be good to go from a basic security standpoint.